# C#の並び替え方法

Tags: c#, sort

現在。C#の勉強中です。
まったくの未経験から練習問題を問いているのですが、
並び替えで行き詰まってしまいました。

以下のコードで、

１．男のみのlist作成
２．女のみのlist作成
３．それぞれのlistのA〜Hを昇順に並べる

という処理を実装したいのですが、
ネットで調べたのですが、
どういう方法があるのかわかりません。
ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

```
class Person
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Gender;
        public Person(string name, string gender)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Gender = gender;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("E 女");
            list.Add("F 女");
            list.Add("G 男");
            list.Add("H 男");
            list.Add("A 女");
            list.Add("B 男");
            list.Add("C 女");
            list.Add("D 男");

            List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

            foreach (string s1 in list)
            {
                string[] splitdata = s1.Split(' ');
                People.Add(new Person(splitdata[0], splitdata[1]));
            }


            foreach (Person a in People)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a.Name, a.Gender);
            }
        }
    }
```

尚、並び替えはLINQを使わず、
出来るだけ、繰り返しや、分岐処理を使い、
並び替えたいのです。

Comment: [List<T>.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) も使わないということですか？

Comment: Listは ArrayListと同等なので配列のように扱うことができます。並び替え（ソート）の手法についてはさまざまなソート手法が存在します。まずはソート手法についてリサーチ下さい。

Comment: 1については質問中に記述のある要素を組み合わせれば簡単に出来るのですが、本当に分からないのでしょうか。であればソートの実装以前に基礎文法レベルの知識が不足しています。

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;

    public string Gender;

    public Person(string name, string gender)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Gender = gender;
    }

    public static Person FromString(string text)
    {
        var array = text.Split(' ');
        return new Person(array[0], array[1]);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<string>
    {
        "E 女",
        "F 女",
        "G 男",
        "H 男",
        "A 女",
        "B 男",
        "C 女",
        "D 男",
    };

    var people = list.Select(_ => Person.FromString(_)).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("people");
    Display(people);
    Console.WriteLine();

    var males = people.Where(_ => _.Gender == "男").ToList();
    OrderByName(males);

    Console.WriteLine("males");
    Display(males);
    Console.WriteLine();

    var females = people.Where(_ => _.Gender == "女").ToList();
    OrderByName(females);

    Console.WriteLine("females");
    Display(females);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

static void Display(IEnumerable<Person> people)
{
    foreach (var person in people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} {person.Gender}");
    }
}

static void OrderByName(List<Person> people)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < people.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (var j = people.Count - 1; j > i; j--)
        {
            if (people[j].Name[0] < people[j - 1].Name[0])
            {
                var temp = people[j - 1];
                people[j - 1] = people[j];
                people[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

とか。

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Sample
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public EGender EnumedGender { get; set; }

        //入力する値が特定のもので固定されている場合、本来ならこのような列挙型を使う方が好ましいです。
        public enum EGender
        {
            Male,
            Female
        }

        public Person(string _name,EGender _gender)
        {
            Name = _name;
            EnumedGender = _gender;
        }

        public Person(string _name,string _gender)
        {
            Name = _name;
            Gender = _gender;
        }

        //インスタンスの内容を文字列で表示するためToStringメソッドを上書きしています。
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + " " + Gender;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            //Block1.整頓されていないリストを作成
            var list = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person("E","女"),
                new Person("F","女"),
                new Person("G","男"),
                new Person("H","男"),
                new Person("A","女"),
                new Person("B","男"),
                new Person("C","女"),
                new Person("D","男")
            };

            //Block2.男女それぞれでリストを作成
            var maleList = new List<Person>();
            var femaleList = new List<Person>();

            //Block3.男女の振り分けを行なう
            foreach (var person in list)
            {
                switch (person.Gender)
                {
                    case "男":
                        maleList.Add(person);
                        break;
                    case "女":
                        femaleList.Add(person);
                        break;
                }
            }

            //それぞれのリストを整頓。
            maleList = asort(maleList).ToList();
            femaleList = asort(femaleList).ToList();

            Display(maleList);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            Display(femaleList);
        }

        //ソート部分は面倒なんで省略。
        private static IEnumerable<Person> asort(IEnumerable<Person> target)
        {
            return target.OrderBy(val => val.Name);
        }

        //出力。
        private static void Display(IEnumerable<Person> target)
        {
            foreach (var person in target)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(person);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

きょう日ソート自体は各種言語の標準機能になりつつあるし、他の人に任せるとして……
提示されているコードについての問題点が幾つかあるのでそっちについて。

- Listを使用しているのにTにPersonを使用していない。
- 初期代入の時点でコンストラクタを使用してデータを入れておけばSplitを使う必要性が無い
- 問題とは関係ないですが、択一形のものならコード中に入れてある列挙型を使用する。択一にstringを使うのはtypoの素です